# PS3 not reading DVD discs, but its reading blu-ray discs. Why?

Tags: ps3

Having issues with my Playstation 3 not reading DVD discs, but its reading blu-ray games and not blu-ray movies. very odd issue. Does anyone know exactly what the issue might be? I'm thinking its either the lens or the drive board that controls the lens. Any insights?

Comment: Basically, it can read games, but not movies?

Comment: Hm, I know the PS2 used to have a similar kind of issue, reading DVDs but not CDs. One of mine did that, I cleaned the lens and it was fixed. Unsure if the PS3's known for the same.

Comment: Try cleaning the lenses: Blu-rays and DVDs are read by different lenses to that's probably the issue.. The blue ray reader uses a diferent lens than the

Comment: It could be a file got corrupted that is used to open the files on the disks for movies. If you reinstall your operating system on the system this may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be the chance that your console is a "dual diode" model. With "dual diode", I mean that it has two different diodes for reading discs, one red for CD and DVD and a blue one for Blu-ray.

Your console might have the red diode for CDs and DVDs burned, but the blue diode for Blu-ray discs is still operational (this is why you can read games, not being able to read movies is probably a bug that makes it think that is required for video discs).

As FAE mentions it in the comments, this is similar failure that is possible on certain PS2 models that use separate CD and DVD diodes.

If you want to check if your console has 2 laser diodes, here is the list of models that use them:

- **Fat**

  - CECHGxx (if manufactured after October 2007)
  - CECHHxx
  - CECHJxx
  - CECHKxx
  - CECHLxx
  - CECHMxx
  - CECHPxx
  - CECHQxx
- **Slim**

  - All Models
- **Super-slim**

  - CECH-40xx